# SVGRectElement comparison

Tags: svg, d3.js, comparison

So I've dynamically created several SVGRectElements in my page using d3 in the   block. Next I use jQuery to fetch the objects I've created by their name and now I have an array of the elements I'm working with. Then I create listeners for these rectangles and have them turn to a different color when I'm hovering over them using mouseover and mouseout in d3. Then I make an click listener which bases the rectangle's object to the function. That function looks like this:

```
function clickBar(bar){
        var barnum = getBarNum(bar);
        output(barnum);
    }
function getBarNum(bar){
    var bars = $("rect");
    output(bar.id+" "+bars[0].id);
    for(i=0; i<=bars.length-1; i++)
    {
        output (bars[i] + " "+bar+" "+i);
        if(bars[i].id==bar.id)
            return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

Via output I'm seeing that in fact SVGRectElements are being compared every time, except never is the index being returned. I know its a different index every time too so asynchronous problems which I've had before can't explain the failure in this comparison. I know == is generally for primitives, but a .equals didn't result in anything different either. How do I do this comparison so that I figure out what index the bar is that I have just clicked?

Comment: It sounds like this would be much much easier using D3 directly rather than going D3 -> JQuery -> D3 -> JQuery. In particular, you're getting all the information you're looking for passed as arguments to the callback.

Comment: That may be, but the fact remains that the comparison never yields the iterator. The result is just an array of SVGRectElements after all which leaves the method I derived it non-essential to the problem. Am I wrong about this? if so, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean -- what's the "iterator" here? My point is that with pure D3, all you have to do is `.on("mouseover", function(d, barnum) { ... })` on the elements to get the index of the bar directly.

Comment: Oh, I see so in the loop in which I set the listeners I should be able to also pass the iterator so that I have that value on hand instead of figuring it out again after the fact when the listener is triggered.

Comment: You don't even need a loop to set the event handlers, you can just install them on the selection.